# Why am I getting this list indices error?

Tags: python, list

Sorry, I'm new to programming so excuse me if my question is lackluster. I want to load these images through the use of a list and a for loop but I keep getting this list error where it says the list indices must be integers or slices. How can I fix this?

code:

```
Images = ['K2', 'G2', 'S2', 'N2', 'L2', 'R2', 'B2', 'P2']

p = []
for n in Images:
    p.append(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'Pieces (set 1)', Images[n] + '.png')))
```

error:

```
p.append(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'Pieces (set 1)', Images[n] + '.png')))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `n` represents each element of the `Images` list. So `Images[n]` part triggers the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Either

```py
for i in range(len(Images)):
    p.append(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'Pieces (set 1)', Images[i] + '.png')))
```

or

```py
for name in Images:
    p.append(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'Pieces (set 1)', name + '.png')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider what values `n` take here: `for n in Images:`. `n` will loop through the elements in `Images`, thus `n` is of type `str`. You cannot use a string as an index to a list `Images[n]`. You probably meant to construct the loop like this: `for n in range(len(Images))`. Then `n` will be integers from 0 to `len(Images) - 1`.